# Re-implement a preference screen in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

In my app, I'm trying to have a list of custom servers, and I want to be able to add them and edit their respective settings individually.

The standard Android `PreferenceFragment` looks and works great for my purposes. Is there a way I can use it to edit selected items? Or, alternatively, can I re-create its look and behavior easily?

In a nutshell :

```
----------------                                    ----------------
|             +|                                    |              |
| Item A       |                                    |  Preference  |
| Item B       |  -->  Click on "A", "B" or "+" --> |    Screen    |
| ...          |                                    |              |
|              |                                    |              |
----------------                                    ----------------
```

Note that I also know how to use a screen hierarchy, and that doesn't fit the bill since I can't add or remove items dynamically, while the app is running.

Comment: The theme is "android:Theme.Holo"... What do you expect?

Comment: I'm not asking about the theme (which I know how to change), I'm asking about using a `PreferenceFragment` dynamically, without having to tie it to an XML resource. See my update, maybe it'll be clearer with a schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to add preferences dynamically in your fragment.. Am I right??

Just look at this sample I found:

```
onCreate(){
    this.setPreferenceScreen(createPreferenceHierarchy());
}

public PreferenceScreen createPreferenceHierarchy(){
    PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

    // category 1 created programmatically
    PreferenceCategory cat1 = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    cat1.setTitle("title");
    root.addPreference(cat1);

    ListPreference list1 = new ListPreference(this);
    list1.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.some_string_title));
    list1.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.some_string_text));      
    list1.setDialogTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.some_string_pick_title));
    list1.setKey("your_key");

    CharSequence[] entries  = calendars.getCalenders(); //or anything else that returns the right data
    list1.setEntries(entries);
    int length              = entries.length;
    CharSequence[] values   = new CharSequence[length];
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        CharSequence val = ""+i+1+"";
        values[i] =  val;
    }
    list1.setEntryValues(values);

    cat1.addPreference(list1);

    return root;
}//end method
```

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I was looking for! I tried Google, but searching for "android custom preference screens" or something didn't exactly yield relevant answers...

Comment: That's what I typed in Google after reading your question: android add preference programmatically

Comment: Woot. Then I must apologize for my lack of insight. Thanks a bunch anyway ;)

Comment: Most important is that you got your answer ;-)